# Challenges with BLoC Pattern: Sequencing Events and Listeners in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a question that has been challenging me quite a bit. I am using BLoC to separate the business logic of the application from the user interface, but I am stuck at a point.

I have my BlocProvider:

```
BlocProvider<RemoteAuthBloc>(
  create: (context) => sl<RemoteAuthBloc>()..add(const GetAuth()),
),
```

Please note that I am adding StartAuth within RemoteAuthBloc, and within it, I can add both GetAuth and StartAuth (here is where the issues begin).

I am making a call in the button's event (onTap) and using it as follows:

```
BlocProvider.of<RemoteAuthBloc>(context).stream.listen((state) {
  if (state is RemoteAuthDone) {
    _go(state.data!);
  }
});
```

Now here is the problem: I need to invoke my _go method in cascade:

```
_go(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  sl<RemoteAuthBloc>().add(StartAuth(data));
  BlocProvider.of<RemoteAuthBloc>(context).stream.listen((state) {
    print("Here");
  });
}
```

I understand that I need to add StartAuth at this moment because it depends on arguments (my data). It wouldn't be possible to add it to BlocProvider simply because I don't have that information yet. Additionally, I can only create the listener after completing the first step of GetAuth. My print("here") is never triggered.

I realize that I might be making a silly mistake due to a lack of knowledge. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I was using another instance of my BLoC.

```
final bloC = BlocProvider.of<RemoteAuthBloc>(context)

[...]

bloC.add(StartAuth(data));
```